# Group algebra, cyclic group, ring isomorphism

Tags: ring-isomorphism, irreducible-representation

Consider the cyclic group $G=\langle g\mid g^{3}=1\rangle$,his group algebra $\mathbb{C}G$ and $\mathbb{R}G$.
As a complex algebra, how to construct an isomorphism between $\mathbb{C}G$ and $\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}$? I also want to know all irreducible representations of $G$. Is there ring isomorphism $\mathbb{R}G\simeq \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: What have you tried? What can you use? Please give more context.